# Parallelizing reduce operation

Tags: java, java-stream

Could a usual 'max' operation as below be distributed as a reduce operation on multiple cores by simply changing stream to parallelstream?
How does the final reconcile  happen (without an explicit combiner) between the outcomes of the different threads?

```
List<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>();
emps.add(new Employee("Roy1",32));
emps.add(new Employee("Roy2",12));
emps.add(new Employee("Roy3",22));
emps.add(new Employee("Roy4",42));
emps.add(new Employee("Roy5",52));

Integer maxSal= emps.parallelStream().mapToInt(e -> e.getSalary()).reduce((a,b)->Math.max(a, b)).getAsInt();

System.out.println("Maximum in parallel " + maxSal);
```

Comment: In this case, the accumulator and combiner are identical—it’s your reduction function. But you can simply call `max()` instead of `.reduce((a,b)->Math.max(a, b))`, to the same result…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `reduce` can be parallelized. However, this requires that you pass an **associative** operator. Excerpt from `java.util.stream` JavaDoc:

> Associativity
>
> An operator or function op is associative if the following holds:
>
> (a op b) op c == a op (b op c)
>
> The importance of this to parallel evaluation can be seen if we expand this to four terms:
>
> a op b op c op d == (a op b) op (c op d)
>
> So we can evaluate (a op b) in parallel with (c op d), and then invoke op on the results. 
>   Examples of associative operations include numeric addition, min, and max, and string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem on parallelizing a stream provided that operations (including inner ones) have good properties. API says (for reduction):

> [...] a properly constructed reduce operation is inherently parallelizable,
>   so long as the function(s) used to process the elements are
>   associative and stateless. [...]

And there is a definition (in the docs) of associative and stateless :

> **Stateless** operations, such as filter and map, retain no state from
>   previously seen element when processing a new element -- each element
>   can be processed independently of operations on other elements.

and

> An operator or function op is **associative** if the following holds:
>
> ```
>  (a op b) op c == a op (b op c)
> ```
>
> The importance of this to parallel evaluation can be seen if we expand this to four terms:
>
> ```
>  a op b op c op d == (a op b) op (c op d)
> ```
>
> So we can evaluate (a op b) in parallel with (c op d), and then invoke op on the results.

Roughly, if operation is associative and stateless that means that you can apply it in any order you want to get the result. So any good generic gathering can be applied. Remember that Java 8 streams are based on Fork-Join pool, so the gathering is well-known. Tutorial on the subject shows the basics:

```
if (my portion of the work is small enough)
  do the work directly
else
  split my work into two pieces
  invoke the two pieces and wait for the results
```